# open bash terminal in a specific directory

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

How can I config bash - I'm using Gnome Terminal - to open the shell into a specific directory?

I know I can insert a cd /directory into .bashrc, but that isn't good enough because if I use Open Terminal Here from a file manager, it will change the directory and prevent this feature to work as it should.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of GNOME Terminal the `--working-directory` argument can be used to set the working directory of the terminal.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

It will really prevent that feature to work since you are *indirectly* specifying in "Open Terminal Here" to open the terminal in the current directory. That's how it should work.

The cd in .bashrc will only work if you run a gnome-terminal not from the context option you mentioned.

As a solution to your problem, you can add an alias to cd to the directory that you want. Let's say you want to cd to /home/someone/directory, add the following to your .bashrc

```
alias cdd="cd /home/someone/directory/"
```